# NSFetchRequest with NSPredicate returning correct results, but whose properties aren't updated

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

My managedObjectContext hierarchy is as follows: (PSC)<-(writerMOC -- private)<-(mainMOC -- main)<-(backgroundMOC -- private)

I have an NSManagedObject who "name" property is "Banana".

In the backgroundMOC, I get a reference to the object with backgroundMOC.objectWithID, change the NSManagedObject's "name" property to "Apple", and subsequently set it's "syncStatus" property to 1 (flagged for synchronization), then recursively save the moc's with the following routine:

```
  func saveManagedContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, shouldSync: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
{
    print("\nSaving managed object context...")
    do {
        try moc.save()
        if let parentContext = moc.parentContext {
            parentContext.performBlock {
                self.saveManagedContext(parentContext, shouldSync: shouldSync, completion: completion)
            }
        }
        else {
            if shouldSync { SyncEngine.sharedInstance.synchronize(shouldPushUpdates: true) }
            completion?()
        }
        print("Finished saving managed object context...")
    } catch {
        logger.error("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Once the last moc is saved, a sync routine is called which does its work on the backgroundMOC, which queries the local store for all objects whose syncStatus is 1, again this fetch is called on the backgroundMOC.

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity.name)
    let syncPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %d", JSONKey.SyncStatus.rawValue, 1)
    fetchRequest.predicate = syncPredicate

    
    return try backgroundMOC.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [SyncableManagedObject] ?? []
```

This correctly returns the updated object in the array, however, that object's syncStatus property equals 0, and its "name" property is still set to "Banana".

This is really causing me headaches, I felt like i had totally understood how managedObjectContext blocks should work, but this has proven to be quite a puzzle.

**UPDATE**
Here's the code that prompts the update. This is called from the main thread when the cell is tapped.

```
  func updateNameForCell(cell: UITableViewCell)
{
    ///gets the object id from the fetchedResultsController
    guard let fruitMetaID = tableController.objectIDForCell(cell) else { return }
    
    let backgroundMOC = CoreDataController.sharedInstance.newBackgroundManagedObjectContext()
    backgroundMOC.performBlock {
        do {
            guard let fruit = (backgroundMOC.objectWithID(fruitMetaID) as? FruitMetaData)?.fruit else {
                throw //Error
            }
         
            print(fruit.name) // "Banana"
            fruit.name = "Apple"
            fruit.needsSynchronization() //Sets syncStatus to 1
            CoreDataController.sharedInstance.saveManagedContext(backgroundMOC)
        }
        catch {
            //handle error
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE AGAIN**
Maybe I'm not creating the contexts right. Enlighten me please!

```
  /// The parent to all other NSManagedObjectContexts. Responsible for writting to the store.
lazy var writerManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext =
{
    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait {
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    }
    return managedObjectContext
}()
 lazy var mainManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext =
{
    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait {
        managedObjectContext.parentContext = self.writerManagedObjectContext
    }

    return managedObjectContext
}()
 /// The context associated with background syncing..
func newBackgroundManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext
{
    let backgroundManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    backgroundManagedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait {
        backgroundManagedObjectContext.parentContext = self.mainManagedObjectContext
    }
    return backgroundManagedObjectContext
}
```

Comment: I should note that the saveManagedContext method is always called within a performBlock of the context passed as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Holding onto child MOCs (children of the main context) is fraught with issues.  I would recommend creating a new child (aka backgroundMOC) for each operation that you do.

Without seeing all of your code this looks like an issue with the child context getting out of sync.

### Update

Assuming that your creation of the `backgroundMOC` sets the `mainMOC` as its parent then I wonder about the `-objectWithID:` and what it is returning.

I also wonder about your `-performBlock:` calls.  In my head the threading looks fine but better to test.  Try changing to `-performBlockAndWait:` just to test and see if there is a threading race condition.  Not a permanent change but eliminates that part of the code as a source of the issue.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: If that does not work, share the code that updates the object's state and the synchronize.  There are some other edge possibilities.

Comment: It didnt work, same problem. I added the code that changes the object property. I had already attached the bulk of the synchronize code, anything else you'd like to see? (the CoreDataController.sharedInstance.saveManagedContext references the previously attached save routine.)

Comment: By the way, all of my previous references to backgroundMOC now call the newBackgroundManagedObjectFunction of my CoreData controller, which gives me a fresh child moc of the main context which isnt held on to. So the fetch now happens on one of these. It doesn't seem like this change has broken anything in my code base.

Comment: Also worth noting, If I move the logic in updateNameForCell() to the main context, all works nicely.

Comment: Responding to your update: The objectWithID call actually returns the appropriate object, when I print the "name", all is accurate. After setting the syncStatus to 1, printing the syncStatus in the block gives the appropriate "1" as well.  Changing the performBlock in updateNameForCell() to a performBlockAndWait() solves the problem, looks like we have a race condition! Interesting though, I was under the impression that since the fetch only happens after all contexts save, a race condition wasnt possible.

Comment: knowing this, do you have any insight on solving the problem with performBlocks?

Comment: Update: performBlockAndWait is no longer working. It working once, and i havnt been able to reproduce the correct results. Very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Before `fetchRequest` is called, you should `reset` context.

```swift
backgroundMOC.reset() // add this line

  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity.name)
    let syncPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %d", JSONKey.SyncStatus.rawValue, 1)
    fetchRequest.predicate = syncPredicate
    return try backgroundMOC.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [SyncableManagedObject] ?? []
```

The reason is `FruitMetaData` is an object(or class) so changing one of its properties/Core Data attributes does not register as a change to the results array ... the object references in the array remain the same.

And `NSFetchRequest` still returns the same result(by using cache). When use `context.reset()`.This tells the context in the extension to fetch new data every time and ignore the cache.